# Header fixed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have tried to fix header in my HTML page using CSS property `position: fixed`. I don't want to use CSS property `position:fixed`. Now is it possible to keep the header fixed in my HTML page using JavaScript without only using CSS property position fixed? It was asked to me in a recent interview.

Comment: You can adjust header element position on scroll but you will have a big performance impact compared to css position fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) property and the [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) and `position:absolute`.

Here is a an example:

```
<html>
 <body>
    <div style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid red; background-color: white;" id="f">fixed</div>
    <div style="height:800px; background-color: #c0c0c0;"></div>
    <div style="height:800px; background-color: #f0f0f0;"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function() { 
            e = document.getElementById('f'); 
            e.style.top = document.body.scrollTop + 1;
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```